# Puppeteer creates bad pdf

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, pdf, puppeteer

I am using puppeteer to create a pdf from my static local html file. The PDF is created but it's corrupted. Adobe reader can't open the file and says - 'Bad file handle'. any suggestions?

I am using below standard code:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('local_html_file', {waitUntil: 'networkidle2'});
  await page.pdf({path: 'hn.pdf', format: 'A4'});

  await browser.close();
})();
```

I also tried setContent() but same result. The page.screenshot() function works however.

Comment: Can you add the html file? and the puppeteer version

Comment: i don't think it's html issue. I tried with just <h1>hello world </h1> line and also with plain text but still same issue.

Comment: what is the version of the puppeteer?

Comment: version 1.20 latest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the pdf filename I gave - 'con.pdf'
This seems to be a reserved name in windows and hence bad file handle. :D
What a coincidence !!!
Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 2):

Probably your code triggers **exception**. You should check pdf file size is not "**zero**" and you can read your pdf file with **less** or **cat** command. Sometimes pdf creators software can write errors to top of the pdf file content.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  try{
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('local_html_file', {waitUntil: 'networkidle2'});
  await page.pdf({path: 'hn.pdf', format: 'A4'});

  await browser.close(); 
  }catch(e){
   console.log(e);
  }
})();
```

Comment: PDF file size is non zero. below is few top line on pdf via less command: %PDF-1.4
%<D3><EB><E9><E1>
1 0 obj
<</Creator (Chromium)
/Producer (Skia/PDF m78)
/CreationDate (D:20191004180831+00'00')
/ModDate (D:20191004180831+00'00')>>
endobj